# Integrating Moonsharp with Unity for Nintendo Switch project

Tags: unity, lua, nintendo, integration

Has anyone tried to run Unity project with integrated Moonsharp on Nintendo Switch? Can it be done? Are there any significant performance issues due to running Lua scripts?

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough about my intentions. I'm working on small project in my spare time and I was wondering if I could try to port my game to Nintendo Switch in future.

The problem is, I don't have my own switch sdk right now, so I can't simply check if integrating Moonsharp is even possible in such scenario. I would like to hear if anyone tried compiling unity project with moonsharp on switch and succeed, or should I look for another runtime scripting engine. I worked with switch SDK in past and I remember that compatiblity issues were real pain.

Comment: We can help you troubleshoot performance problems if you can show us profiling from your test cases. If you haven't tested this yet, please do that first. Your performance is rarely dictated by your language or runtime — how you're using it in the context of your game is the most important factor. One dev may find it was unbearably slow running 1000 Lua scripts at once, but if you need only 5 then their data point is irrelevant to your situation. So doing a synthetic test representative of your use case will be more informative than any Internet stranger's opinion.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear enough. I eddited my question.